# State is not updating immediately function component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'd like to run the map function after the state has been updated. But what is currently happening is that the map function renders the element even before the state is updated due it's asynchronous nature. Is there a way a callback after the state is updated in function based components ? Thanks in advance.

```
 const[arrDeliveryDetails,setArrDeliveryDetails]=useState([
         {id:0,TradeCode:'AZ-120', ExpectedQuantity:0, DeliveredQuantity:0, ItemDeliveryStatus:1},
         {id:1,TradeCode:'AZ-121', ExpectedQuantity:1, DeliveredQuantity:1, ItemDeliveryStatus:1},
         {id:2,TradeCode:'AZ-122', ExpectedQuantity:2, DeliveredQuantity:2, ItemDeliveryStatus:1},
         {id:3,TradeCode:'AZ-123', ExpectedQuantity:3, DeliveredQuantity:3, ItemDeliveryStatus:1},
     ])}

    const updateStatus= (key,value)=>
    {  
        let update = [...arrDeliveryDetails]
        update[key] = {...update[key], ItemDeliveryStatus:value}
        setArrDeliveryDetails(update)

         arrDeliveryDetails.map((items)=>{ 
            console.log(items)
            items.ItemDeliveryStatus=="1" ?
                setPendingCount(prev=>prev+1)                              
            :items.ItemDeliveryStatus=="2" ?
                setDeliveredCount(prev=>prev+1)
            : items.ItemDeliveryStatus=="3" ?               
                setCompletedCount(prev=>prev+1)
            :   setReturnedCount(prev=>prev+1)
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

The state should not be used right after the state update as the value must affect the state variable after the render cycle.

instead of using the state, we can use the value that we are applying the new value to the state.

for ex.

```
let update = [...arrDeliveryDetails]
        update[key] = {...update[key], ItemDeliveryStatus:value}
        setArrDeliveryDetails(update)

         update.map((items)=>{ 
            console.log(items)
            items.ItemDeliveryStatus=="1" ?
                setPendingCount(prev=>prev+1)                              
            :items.ItemDeliveryStatus=="2" ?
                setDeliveredCount(prev=>prev+1)
            : items.ItemDeliveryStatus=="3" ?               
                setCompletedCount(prev=>prev+1)
            :   setReturnedCount(prev=>prev+1)
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can't because `setArrDeliveryDetails` is async and you don't know when `arrDeliveryDetails` will be updated (it's how React works).

Simply use the local variable `update`:

```
const updateStatus= (key,value)=>
    {  
        let update = [...arrDeliveryDetails]
        update[key] = {...update[key], ItemDeliveryStatus:value}
        setArrDeliveryDetails(update)

         update.map((items)=>{ 
            console.log(items)
            items.ItemDeliveryStatus=="1" ?
                setPendingCount(prev=>prev+1)                              
            :items.ItemDeliveryStatus=="2" ?
                setDeliveredCount(prev=>prev+1)
            : items.ItemDeliveryStatus=="3" ?               
                setCompletedCount(prev=>prev+1)
            :   setReturnedCount(prev=>prev+1)
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

**Setting a state in react is an asynchronous process.**

You cannot get access to updated data directly after setState.

So in this case you can use `useEffect` and put your `state` variable inside the dependency array.

```
useEffect(() => {
    arrDeliveryDetails.map((items)=>{ 
       console.log(items)
       items.ItemDeliveryStatus=="1" ?
          setPendingCount(prev=>prev+1)                              
       :items.ItemDeliveryStatus=="2" ?
          setDeliveredCount(prev=>prev+1)
       : items.ItemDeliveryStatus=="3" ?               
          setCompletedCount(prev=>prev+1)
       :   setReturnedCount(prev=>prev+1)
  })
}, [arrDeliveryDetails]);
```